# how to persist data for two forms

Tags: php, symfony

I have a page that contains two forms, each form is displayed by clicking on a tab, and each of them has  a button "add", the problem is when I click add either the first or the second form I can't persist data in the database.
thank you for your help
Here are the tow actions to persist he two forms:
Controller.php

```
public function ajouterPSAction()
  {  
     $affairePS = new AffairePanneauSolaire;
     $affairePC = new AffairePompeChaleur;
     $form1 = $this->createForm(new AffairePanneauSolaireType(), $affairePS);
     $form = $this->createForm(new AffairePanneauSolaireType(), $affairePC);
     $req = $this->get('request');

    if( $req->getMethod() === 'POST' )
    {       

            $form1->bind($req);
            if ($form1->isValid()) {
              $em = $this->getDoctrine()
                          ->getManager();

              $em->persist($affairePS); 
              $em->flush();
              // On définit un message flash
              $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'Affaire bien ajouté');     
      // Puis on redirige vers la page de visualisation :
      return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl('affaire_voir_affairePS', array(
                                                                                 'id' => $affairePS->getId()
            )) ); }
  }
  // Si on n'est pas en POST, alors on affiche le formulaire
    return $this->render('AffaireBundle:Affaires:ajouter.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(),'form1' => $form1->createView()));
  }
public function ajouterPCAction()
  { 
     $affairePC = new AffairePompeChaleur;
     $affairePS =  new AffairePanneauSolaire;
     $form = $this->createForm(new AffairePompeChaleurType(), $affairePC);
     $form1 = $this->createForm(new AffairePanneauSolaireType(), $affairePS);
     $req = $this->get('request');
     if( $req->getMethod() === 'POST' )
    {       
       $form->bind($req);
       if ($form->isValid()) {
       $em = $this->getDoctrine()
                   ->getManager();
       $em->persist($affairePC);
       $em->flush();
          // On définit un message flash
              $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'Affaire bien ajouté');     
      // Puis on redirige vers la page de visualisation :
      return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl('affaire_voir_affairePC', array(
                                                                                 'id' => $affairePC->getId()
            )) ); }
  }
  // Si on n'est pas en POST, alors on affiche le formulaire
  return $this->render('AffaireBundle:Affaires:ajouter.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(),'form1' => $form1->createView()));
  }
```

---

for the two actions ajouterPSAction and ajouterPCaction, i let them as they are?? or i must spend for every action the new form??
to display the tow form as 2 tab i let it like this??

```
 <div class="tabbable">
                            <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs" style="width: 1270px;">
                                <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Pompe à chaleur</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Panneaux solaires</a></li>


                            </ul>
                            <div class="tab-content" style="float: left;">
                                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">{% include "AffaireBundle:Affaires:formulairePC.html.twig" %} </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane fade in " id="profile"> {% include "AffaireBundle:Affaires:formulairePS.html.twig" %}</div>

                             </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try make it one form, but display in 2 tabs:

- create a new entity which have 2 field `$affairePS` (`AffairePanneauSolaire`) and `$affairePC` (`AffairePompeChaleur`)
- implement getters and setters for those 2 fields
- create a new form class with `data_class` of newly created form
- render the new form within 1 `<form>`, but display as 2 tabs, both tabs have submit button

Form class code:

```
class BarType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('affairePS', new AffairePanneauSolaireType())
            ->add('affairePC', new AffairePompeChaleurType())
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'data_class' => 'Path\To\New\Entity',
            )
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'foo_bar_type';
    }
}
```

Action code:

```
public function fooAction()
{
    $newFormEntity = new \Path\To\New\Entity();
    $newFormEntity->setAffairePS(new AffairePanneauSolaire());
    $newFormEntity->setAffairePC(new AffairePompeChaleur());
    $form = $this->createForm(new BarType(), $newFormEntity);
}
```